# Azure Adding Additional Address Space to Local Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to add Additional Address spaces to the Local Network Gateway in my Azure Virtual Network, but I keep getting an error everytime I try do this.

The error is the following:
Failed to save configuration changes to local network gateway 'wintech-01-lgw'. Error: There was an error processing your request. Try again in a few moments.

Currently I have the following Address Spaces there:
10.10.2.0/24
10.10.40.0/24
I added these when I initially setup the site-to-site VPN connection and virtual network. But now I want to add additional address spaces (10.10.3.0/24) and I keep getting the above error??

Attached is a screenprint of what it looks like from the console.
[Azure Error Screenprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Yaj.png)

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell/#to-modify-ip-address-prefixes-for-a-local-site)

1. Remove the gateway connection.
2. Modify the prefixes for your local
   site.
3. Create a new gateway connection.

or have you already tried using this method?